# How can I see the specific value of the sql_mode?

Tags: mysql

There are some `sql_mode` values in MySQL:

`ANSI`,

`IGNORE_SPACE`,

`STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`, etc

How can I see the one particular value? The manual says:

> You can retrieve the current mode by issuing a SELECT @@sql_mode
>   statement.

But it just shows nothing, just one blank field in a table with `@@sql_mode` as a column name.

Answer (score 203, accepted):

It's only blank for you because you have not set the sql_mode. If you set it, then that query will show you the details:

```
mysql> SELECT @@sql_mode;
+------------+
| @@sql_mode |
+------------+
|            |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> set sql_mode=ORACLE;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @@sql_mode;
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @@sql_mode                                                                                                           |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| PIPES_AS_CONCAT,ANSI_QUOTES,IGNORE_SPACE,ORACLE,NO_KEY_OPTIONS,NO_TABLE_OPTIONS,NO_FIELD_OPTIONS,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. But some of them have their default values. I meant I wanted to see the defaults without setting the value. Or it's not possible?

Comment: The combination modes are all documented here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html. For example, here you can see which 7 modes comprise the ORACLE combination mode: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_oracle

Comment: "The default SQL mode is empty (no modes set)." Quoted from the MySQL Server Administration manual page for [Server SQL Modes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html). I interpret that to mean that _none_ of the special sql_mode's are set out of the box.

Comment: @IkeWalker, Do you mean to say that by default (the "blank" mode), it is equivalent to as though all of `PIPES_AS_CONCAT,ANSI_QUOTES,IGNORE_SPACE,ORACLE,NO_KEY_OPTIONS,NO_TABLE_OPTIONS,NO_FIELD_OPTIONS,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER` and etc are **not** set? Or do you mean that some of them are set but simply not shown by default?

Comment: @Pacerier the former is correct. If @@sql_mode is empty (the "blank" mode as you call it), then *no* sql_mode is set. I won't comment on the default sql_mode because that depends which version of MySQL you are running.

Answer (score 34):

You can also try this to determine the current *global* `sql_mode` value:

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
```

or *session* `sql_mode` value:

```
SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;
```

I also had the feeling that the *SQL mode* was indeed empty.

Comment: official doc: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-setting

Answer (score 10):

You need to login to your mysql terminal first using
`mysql -u username -p password`

Then use this:

```
SELECT @@sql_mode; or SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
```

output will be like this:

STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,STRICT_ALL_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,TRADITIONAL,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUB

You can also set sql mode by this:

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=TRADITIONAL;
```