# How to check the SQL_MODE in mysql for a single process?

Tags: mysql, sql-mode

How can I check what SQL_MODE is a process is using?

so I see all processed that are currently running using `SHOW PROCESSLIST`

What I need to do is to know the SQL_MODE that a process is using?

I want to make sure the client that I am using did not change the SQL mode.

Thanks

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46277941/6064933

Answer (score 7):

Refer to [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-mode.html).

```
To determine the current global or session sql_mode value, use the following statements:

SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;
```

You are primarily interested in the @@SESSION.sql_mode variable.

Comment: No, this only works for the current session you are on but does not give you the session of **another** client.