# Is possible to have more than 1 sql_mode simultaneously in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to setup two sql_modes on MySQL, but when I setup the second, then the first is replacing:

`SET sql_mode=ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY;`

And check for the current sql_mode in MySQL:

```
  ------------------
 |SELECT @@sql_mode |
  ------------------
 |ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY|
  ------------------
```

When I tried to setup another mode (I want to get ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY also) I do:

`SET sql_mode=PIPES_AS_CONCAT`

Again, I check the current sql_mode in MySQL, but I notice that only 1 sql_mode is setup:

```
  ------------------
 |SELECT @@sql_mode |
  ------------------
 |PIPES_AS_CONCAT   |
  ------------------
```

I want to get:

```
  ------------------
 |SELECT @@sql_mode |
  ------------------
 |ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY|
  ------------------
 |PIPES_AS_CONCAT   |
  ------------------
```

Any idea of whats happening?

I also check [How can I see the specific value of the sql_mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591231/how-can-i-see-the-specific-value-of-the-sql-mode) and [SQL Mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-mode.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put both of them in quotes separated by a `,`.  Otherwise, you will overwrite the setting when you run the second `set` command.

```
mysql> set sql_mode="PIPES_AS_CONCAT,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY";
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like '%sql_mode%';
+---------------+------------------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                              |
+---------------+------------------------------------+
| sql_mode      | PIPES_AS_CONCAT,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY |
+---------------+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks!. Before your answer I tried some similar but without quotes (`SET sql_mode=PIPES_AS_CONCAT,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` and doesn't worked, but I don't figure that the quotes are necesary).

Comment: nice, I was stumped what any of this even meant