# How to filter by most recent date in a 3 table SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Mysql database of a school, where for each Course (pj001_courses), there are one ore more related lessons (tasks). In the middle there is a joining table (pj001_courses_tasks_c).

pj001_courses:  (id, name)

pj001_courses_tasks_c:  (id, pj001_courses_taskspj001_courses_ida, pj001_courses_taskstasks_idb)

tasks:  (id, name, date_start, date_modified, status)

WHERE:  pj001_courses.id = pj001_courses_tasks_c.pj001_courses_taskspj001_courses_ida 
AND
tasks.id = pj001_courses_tasks_c. pj001_courses_taskstasks_idb

What I’m trying to obtain with my query, is a list of all the courses with the most recent ‘completed’ lesson (status=’completed’), that will include the following fields:

Corso,
Id corso,
idlez,
Lezione,
date_start,
date_modified

Here below, you can find the code to create a sample mysql test database:

```html
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.0.10deb1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generato il: Apr 07, 2017 alle 08:24
-- Versione del server: 5.5.53-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
-- Versione PHP: 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `speak_italy_stov`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Struttura della tabella `pj001_courses`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pj001_courses` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_entered` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_user_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `deleted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `assigned_user_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `startdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `startlevel` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lessonsday` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;

--
-- Dump dei dati per la tabella `pj001_courses`
--

INSERT INTO `pj001_courses` (`id`, `name`, `date_entered`, `date_modified`, `modified_user_id`, `created_by`, `description`, `deleted`, `assigned_user_id`, `startdate`, `startlevel`, `time`, `lessonsday`) VALUES
('3d87bac4-49b0-3acb-3010-56684570afd9', 'Course1', '2015-12-09 15:14:11', '2017-04-06 14:09:28', '1', '1', NULL, 0, '', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
('bb9311ed-8e1b-7715-9222-565f2e684b49', 'Course2', '2015-12-02 17:48:24', '2017-04-06 12:29:58', '1', 'e07880a3-a57d-a20c-9e25-565eb7af093f', NULL, 0, '', '2015-10-14', '80+', '12.45', '^Tuesday^,^Friday^'),
('c608ec6d-960e-eb4f-760d-577b81007df9', 'Course3', '2016-07-05 09:43:30', '2017-04-06 12:31:22', '1', '1', NULL, 0, '', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
('ce7c7bb1-c511-82e5-40bf-56616a7a10cc', 'Course4', '2015-12-04 10:27:39', '2017-04-06 12:35:11', '1', 'c0aa6b17-16d0-baea-c4ae-566162ba3706', NULL, 0, '', '2015-10-05', '10', '10.45', '^Monday^,^Thursday^'),
('eb914486-79d6-07e6-8263-566188671f7a', 'Course5', '2015-12-04 12:33:05', '2016-06-28 13:23:41', '1', 'e07880a3-a57d-a20c-9e25-565eb7af093f', NULL, 0, '', '2015-10-12', 'L.41', '17.00', '^Monday^,^Thursday^'),
('f05b48a8-5a13-5e9f-a823-58e6373e80d7', 'Course6', '2017-04-06 12:41:06', '2017-04-06 12:41:06', '1', '1', NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, '', '', '');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Struttura della tabella `pj001_courses_tasks_c`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pj001_courses_tasks_c` (
  `id` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `pj001_courses_taskspj001_courses_ida` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pj001_courses_taskstasks_idb` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `pj001_courses_tasks_ida1` (`pj001_courses_taskspj001_courses_ida`),
  KEY `pj001_courses_tasks_alt` (`pj001_courses_taskstasks_idb`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;

--
-- Dump dei dati per la tabella `pj001_courses_tasks_c`
--

INSERT INTO `pj001_courses_tasks_c` (`id`, `date_modified`, `deleted`, `pj001_courses_taskspj001_courses_ida`, `pj001_courses_taskstasks_idb`) VALUES
('115cbbd6-a061-5ba8-feb4-56756fa6fa6c', '2015-12-19 14:55:56', 0, '3d87bac4-49b0-3acb-3010-56684570afd9', 'fb94089f-57e9-0918-c98f-56756fa424d4'),
('16ed5813-c5d1-f831-9887-56efc618e85a', '2017-04-06 12:18:23', 1, '3d87bac4-49b0-3acb-3010-56684570afd9', '15c65e64-83d5-e27e-9ded-56efc6034ec7'),
('17ef5857-b4a6-6dbf-dedd-58cf9a076172', '2017-03-20 09:03:40', 1, '3d87bac4-49b0-3acb-3010-56684570afd9', '1756da3f-3356-1dea-96b4-58cf9adab8ea'),
('1d05994a-45fa-0370-5304-58cf9b51f8e1', '2017-03-20 09:04:53', 1, '3d87bac4-49b0-3acb-3010-56684570afd9', '1c7f7856-11e6-22a7-786b-58cf9b7d42f4'),
('211b53d7-3bb3-5afe-af27-58cf9ac53d35', '2017-03-20 09:03:40', 1, '3d87bac4-49b0-3acb-3010-56684570afd9', '2092dc4e-ad01-34b8-0b80-58cf9a0b0c90'),
('23e767e6-a6c1-304f-92e3-5671a4ec937d', '2017-04-06 12:38:05', 1, 'eb914486-79d6-07e6-8263-566188671f7a', '226c2475-16a3-e0af-efaa-5671a483f0e2'),
('24c80d60-f81d-c32f-a368-56684568c447', '2015-12-09 15:16:30', 0, 'eb914486-79d6-07e6-8263-566188671f7a', '18f60d90-0554-4880-760b-5668455dd961'),
('27228e24-b7ab-a384-8fe6-58cf9bdbcd56', '2017-03-20 09:04:53', 1, '3d87bac4-49b0-3acb-3010-56684570afd9', '26af672a-823d-2d07-2146-58cf9be2b6f2'),
('284f980c-9dab-2a7f-3526-57738ad682dc', '2017-04-06 12:18:23', 1, '3d87bac4-49b0-3acb-3010-56684570afd9', '2733a707-e734-6a68-c63c-57738a212cd3'),
('2be389fe-1c71-ebde-414e-56616dc0040d', '2015-12-04 10:41:15', 0, 'ce7c7bb1-c511-82e5-40bf-56616a7a10cc', '2996ca74-f2d5-a0bf-0c92-56616d7db8d4'),
('2fdea17a-a236-95b0-586f-58cf9b041a93', '2017-03-20 09:04:53', 1, '3d87bac4-49b0-3acb-3010-56684570afd9', '2f72251d-5ca1-9890-1dc7-58cf9b790e86'),
('30afc042-2d41-ad85-1ace-566b214472a2', '2015-12-11 19:16:20', 0, '3d87bac4-49b0-3acb-3010-56684570afd9', '2f19dd24-1c2f-a245-1856-566b214d7abd'),
('386ce887-a266-8ef6-7d07-58cf9b0b74bb', '2017-03-20 09:04:53', 1, '3d87bac4-49b0-3acb-3010-56684570afd9', '37f7bc74-46c4-0094-f3ad-58cf9b2f00f6'),
('3ac48770-4ed0-fd25-b87f-56616ec579cf', '2015-12-04 10:45:59', 0, 'ce7c7bb1-c511-82e5-40bf-56616a7a10cc', '39109517-1f24-8048-4fca-56616e12fc48'),
('3e440aab-0536-7521-7ac5-5668440a96d9', '2015-12-09 15:13:02', 0, 'bb9311ed-8e1b-7715-9222-565f2e684b49', '16ce0346-064f-c93e-19ca-5668427c30b4'),
('4ab9d6f9-0e63-a8c4-5b7a-58cfd830770a', '2017-04-06 12:18:23', 1, '3d87bac4-49b0-3acb-3010-56684570afd9', '4a1d0654-39fe-1c37-7c0c-58cfd8bd7105'),
('4f02bb09-7576-b8bc-7187-58cf9cee8060', '2017-03-20 09:12:42', 1, '3d87bac4-49b0-3acb-3010-56684570afd9', '4e78ed60-24c8-fcf8-7b62-58cf9ccac2b4'),
('4faff722-1eb8-05ec-2ffe-56718c87b046', '2017-04-06 12:37:27', 1, 'eb914486-79d6-07e6-8263-566188671f7a', '4dd39006-f652-3ae1-d6a6-56718c46617e'),
('59d2498f-8931-7716-3e7b-58e64b5ae4c1', '2017-04-06 14:08:03', 0, '3d87bac4-49b0-3acb-3010-56684570afd9', '595a2e58-76bc-c134-3cef-58e64b59e8d5'),
('5c3f2895-e160-04e9-d79e-58cfd8565416', '2017-03-20 13:26:40', 0, '3d87bac4-49b0-3acb-3010-56684570afd9', '5ba36af1-8f2b-075b-926f-58cfd87a83e7'),
('672b6c68-fcc6-3945-7a47-58cfd8b2d040', '2017-04-06 12:18:23', 1, '3d87bac4-49b0-3acb-3010-56684570afd9', '66a5b45f-4173-387f-8f3d-58cfd8f91b9d'),
('6944176d-6f2b-3369-1e76-5672a363aa43', '2017-04-06 12:38:27', 1, 'eb914486-79d6-07e6-8263-566188671f7a', '6693cd37-0b74-1d97-c395-5672a343260d'),
('6ce06c21-5db1-a921-a37e-57729c1877d4', '2017-04-06 12:18:23', 1, '3d87bac4-49b0-3acb-3010-56684570afd9', '743cf2ca-e983-2f08-a2fb-5772966547a1'),
('6d43042f-8f79-8d06-7d9e-58cf9bed69db', '2017-03-20 09:10:57', 1, '3d87bac4-49b0-3acb-3010-56684570afd9', '65730b79-3f6e-4385-c83e-58cf9b3a6cb4'),
('6e8d9e2b-0300-4b67-b639-58cf9cc1d141', '2017-03-20 09:12:42', 1, '3d87bac4-49b0-3acb-3010-56684570afd9', '6e1bd69b-6501-95d5-1aa8-58cf9c44c529'),
('70d706d1-ddba-1174-e73a-58cfd83ed1e5', '2017-04-06 12:18:23', 1, '3d87bac4-49b0-3acb-3010-56684570afd9', '705d3dad-8f77-04a6-05c5-58cfd8124fd5'),
('7613bd00-0397-5b93-5aa9-57738ba67cca', '2016-06-29 08:47:35', 0, '3d87bac4-49b0-3acb-3010-56684570afd9', '7488d168-758c-f760-ed28-57738b5565db'),
('78107ede-3f85-80f6-bad0-56718c341009', '2015-12-16 16:09:30', 0, 'eb914486-79d6-07e6-8263-566188671f7a', '760f5ee8-6470-9291-6733-56718c949974'),
('790ba77f-4723-e52a-b991-58cf9c9da98c', '2017-03-20 09:12:42', 1, '3d87bac4-49b0-3acb-3010-56684570afd9', '788c0fcf-c454-c9fb-3af3-58cf9c82b7d3'),
('81af0547-2f08-61d6-ed81-577b8160db2a', '2016-07-05 09:44:33', 0, 'c608ec6d-960e-eb4f-760d-577b81007df9', '80859612-d91f-bd91-8198-577b81c9dd09'),
('852fc19f-2f48-942f-0ecc-58cf9c5abcc7', '2017-03-20 09:12:42', 1, '3d87bac4-49b0-3acb-3010-56684570afd9', '8462c635-7ccc-dc53-d152-58cf9c3d0222'),
('87a6b49d-5943-4a26-7193-566aac243068', '2017-04-06 12:18:23', 1, '3d87bac4-49b0-3acb-3010-56684570afd9', '85bd5d08-110b-5bce-f564-566aac8ffa97'),
('8aec1222-0b3e-b509-5801-58e63152154f', '2017-04-06 12:16:49', 0, '3d87bac4-49b0-3acb-3010-56684570afd9', '8a635f3b-9e0f-16aa-5532-58e631257729'),
('936b09a7-3940-e350-6815-56616eeff1c5', '2015-12-04 10:43:35', 0, 'ce7c7bb1-c511-82e5-40bf-56616a7a10cc', '92a4c747-b1b7-2949-bcf6-56616ee3b065'),
('9a2359bb-6fc9-ed44-7c81-58cfb514f537', '2017-03-20 13:26:13', 1, '3d87bac4-49b0-3acb-3010-56684570afd9', '999d63e2-67a7-b3a2-b236-58cfb505406b'),
('9b3b1f2b-3e3e-30fe-e9a5-58cf9de1a73b', '2017-03-20 10:57:33', 1, '3d87bac4-49b0-3acb-3010-56684570afd9', '9aac98ea-703d-5aef-391d-58cf9d973ff2'),
('9f230245-53e5-cd01-e775-577b8404ac60', '2016-07-05 09:58:43', 0, 'c608ec6d-960e-eb4f-760d-577b81007df9', '8c8404b6-4e53-5f2b-fcce-577b84f9dceb'),
('9f97d432-9484-5417-7818-58e6352168ff', '2017-04-06 12:34:10', 0, 'ce7c7bb1-c511-82e5-40bf-56616a7a10cc', '9ecdc18e-9187-da7e-54d9-58e635cddf77'),
('a2a1b248-dd8a-a7cd-fca6-56616e6c40c8', '2015-12-04 10:43:35', 0, 'ce7c7bb1-c511-82e5-40bf-56616a7a10cc', 'a2058842-e181-b794-6343-56616ef2e0b2'),
('a680033e-316b-ef9b-0dde-58cf9d9c632a', '2017-03-20 10:57:33', 1, '3d87bac4-49b0-3acb-3010-56684570afd9', 'a5fc3006-fd64-e9dc-fb94-58cf9d5debdc'),
('a81bbdd2-b462-b6d5-55a7-567673ca4ad5', '2015-12-20 09:25:15', 0, 'ce7c7bb1-c511-82e5-40bf-56616a7a10cc', 'a6c97a12-c6b4-f178-acc1-567673523d06'),
('af0ef471-7dca-da91-6bc7-56616e9eb398', '2017-04-06 12:32:45', 1, 'ce7c7bb1-c511-82e5-40bf-56616a7a10cc', 'ae606f3d-5370-9abf-369a-56616e559357'),
('af4cbeee-9f5a-d55a-5fbc-58cf9d6f385e', '2017-03-20 10:57:33', 1, '3d87bac4-49b0-3acb-3010-56684570afd9', 'aed7b370-1c60-2390-716c-58cf9d9f3d0c'),
('b530b867-498a-bd70-65cc-58cfb526254b', '2017-03-20 13:26:13', 1, '3d87bac4-49b0-3acb-3010-56684570afd9', 'b4b53dca-3ca7-a5ad-84fd-58cfb507e8a0'),
('b7d42855-3f4a-4bec-ada7-58cf9def096e', '2017-03-20 10:57:33', 1, '3d87bac4-49b0-3acb-3010-56684570afd9', 'b75a7e3a-3a04-e644-bbeb-58cf9de32173'),
('ba70dbac-b9c4-b01a-ceb7-56616ef2ea42', '2017-04-06 12:32:45', 1, 'ce7c7bb1-c511-82e5-40bf-56616a7a10cc', 'b9d7250f-4971-05b8-ebe2-56616e43f6bc'),
('c02eaa05-8b85-9af0-e9e8-58cfb53f574b', '2017-03-20 13:26:13', 1, '3d87bac4-49b0-3acb-3010-56684570afd9', 'bf7d328c-47d4-8d1c-bafe-58cfb5cc2d81'),
('cb55beaf-b39f-8d78-c379-58cfb503c909', '2017-03-20 13:26:13', 1, '3d87bac4-49b0-3acb-3010-56684570afd9', 'cadc200c-4de2-9c78-f75a-58cfb5f67856'),
('cd3a0876-9928-64ec-2d1f-566aab4e8926', '2015-12-11 10:56:48', 0, 'bb9311ed-8e1b-7715-9222-565f2e684b49', 'b15c0722-19da-79bf-51b2-566aabefc417'),
('d24a2cd1-0922-9e67-3c8a-56616fa70aef', '2017-04-06 12:32:45', 1, 'ce7c7bb1-c511-82e5-40bf-56616a7a10cc', 'd203b35d-38b2-3d9c-1b46-56616f474d3c'),
('d91d8d9d-6852-25e9-5f0b-56616f917b61', '2017-04-06 12:32:45', 1, 'ce7c7bb1-c511-82e5-40bf-56616a7a10cc', 'd8c9630e-4299-6767-e0c4-56616f979c7e'),
('db20a6c0-30b6-87d4-dd8f-577b8154c1b5', '2016-07-05 09:44:04', 0, 'c608ec6d-960e-eb4f-760d-577b81007df9', 'd9fed2e5-a303-e3d6-0c0c-577b814f9e4c'),
('de0951ca-9677-b28e-99a9-56616f275c90', '2017-04-06 12:32:45', 1, 'ce7c7bb1-c511-82e5-40bf-56616a7a10cc', 'ddc93703-d567-a464-22bc-56616f69224c'),
('e4c778d6-5edf-a815-afb4-58cf9bc573f8', '2017-03-20 09:10:57', 1, '3d87bac4-49b0-3acb-3010-56684570afd9', 'e44fe420-a396-d951-cb7c-58cf9ba34f8a'),
('e61ea6cf-aafc-b1d8-f7d8-56616ff24565', '2017-04-06 12:32:45', 1, 'ce7c7bb1-c511-82e5-40bf-56616a7a10cc', 'e5ce5ab1-2e65-2235-400e-56616fb9f5f6'),
('e9c70b0c-f5d5-c08f-4249-58cf9a23ca90', '2017-03-20 09:03:40', 1, '3d87bac4-49b0-3acb-3010-56684570afd9', 'e1ce0b22-74ab-11e8-b4c8-58cf9a86acf8'),
('ebe3092e-a344-00f4-8b5e-57728661f273', '2017-04-06 12:18:23', 1, '3d87bac4-49b0-3acb-3010-56684570afd9', 'c3d209bb-0a2b-a6a9-f215-5772867b4603'),
('ee071730-fd54-a102-de1e-58cf9a9662fd', '2017-03-20 09:03:55', 1, '3d87bac4-49b0-3acb-3010-56684570afd9', 'ed65a8a5-f409-b7f2-c171-58cf9a17cc85'),
('eee4ddd2-d929-838f-2527-58cf9bf35c6b', '2017-03-20 09:10:57', 1, '3d87bac4-49b0-3acb-3010-56684570afd9', 'ee7c27b6-9739-e6d0-7749-58cf9b82a093'),
('f1470127-1225-5257-b1cc-58cf9bea895c', '2017-03-20 09:10:57', 1, '3d87bac4-49b0-3acb-3010-56684570afd9', 'e9f2030e-76f7-852e-3e7d-58cf9b407424');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Struttura della tabella `tasks`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tasks` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_entered` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_user_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `deleted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `assigned_user_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(100) DEFAULT 'Not Started',
  `date_due_flag` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `date_due` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_start_flag` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `date_start` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `priority` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_tsk_name` (`name`),
  KEY `idx_task_con_del` (`contact_id`,`deleted`),
  KEY `idx_task_par_del` (`parent_id`,`parent_type`,`deleted`),
  KEY `idx_task_assigned` (`assigned_user_id`),
  KEY `idx_task_status` (`status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;

--
-- Dump dei dati per la tabella `tasks`
--

INSERT INTO `tasks` (`id`, `name`, `date_entered`, `date_modified`, `modified_user_id`, `created_by`, `description`, `deleted`, `assigned_user_id`, `status`, `date_due_flag`, `date_due`, `date_start_flag`, `date_start`, `parent_type`, `parent_id`, `contact_id`, `priority`) VALUES
('15c65e64-83d5-e27e-9ded-56efc6034ec7', 'c1lesson1', '2016-03-21 10:02:12', '2017-04-06 12:18:23', '1', '1', NULL, 1, '1', 'Completed', 0, '2016-03-18 10:45:00', 0, '2016-03-18 10:00:00', NULL, '', '', 'High'),
('16ce0346-064f-c93e-19ca-5668427c30b4', 'c2lesson_first_completed', '2015-12-09 15:03:11', '2017-04-06 12:29:16', '1', '1', NULL, 0, '1', 'Completed', 0, '2015-12-10 11:00:00', 0, '2015-12-10 10:00:00', NULL, '', '', 'High'),
('18f60d90-0554-4880-760b-5668455dd961', 'c5lesson1', '2015-12-09 15:16:30', '2017-04-06 12:36:42', '1', '1', NULL, 0, '1', 'Not Started', 0, '2015-12-12 11:00:00', 0, '2015-12-12 10:00:00', NULL, '', '', 'High'),
('226c2475-16a3-e0af-efaa-5671a483f0e2', 'nocourse_lesson2', '2015-12-16 17:52:23', '2017-04-06 12:40:24', '1', '1', NULL, 0, '1', 'Not Started', 0, '2015-12-17 11:00:00', 0, '2015-12-17 10:00:00', NULL, '', '', 'High'),
('2996ca74-f2d5-a0bf-0c92-56616d7db8d4', 'c4lesson3', '2015-12-04 10:41:15', '2017-04-06 12:34:36', '1', 'c0aa6b17-16d0-baea-c4ae-566162ba3706', NULL, 0, 'c0aa6b17-16d0-baea-c4ae-566162ba3706', 'Completed', 0, '2015-10-05 09:30:00', 0, '2015-10-05 08:45:00', NULL, '', '', 'High'),
('2f19dd24-1c2f-a245-1856-566b214d7abd', 'c1lesson_last_completed', '2015-12-11 19:16:20', '2017-04-06 12:26:34', '1', '1', NULL, 0, '1', 'Completed', 0, '2015-12-16 11:00:00', 0, '2015-12-16 10:00:00', NULL, '', '', 'High'),
('39109517-1f24-8048-4fca-56616e12fc48', 'c4lesson4', '2015-12-04 10:45:59', '2017-04-06 12:35:11', '1', 'c0aa6b17-16d0-baea-c4ae-566162ba3706', NULL, 0, 'c0aa6b17-16d0-baea-c4ae-566162ba3706', 'Completed', 0, '2015-10-08 09:30:00', 0, '2015-10-08 08:45:00', NULL, '', '', 'High'),
('3b0e7a1e-543c-ea43-5a5c-565ee2d8a787', 'GWENT - VR', '2015-12-02 12:20:48', '2017-04-06 12:39:20', '1', 'e07880a3-a57d-a20c-9e25-565eb7af093f', NULL, 0, '36fcf0ba-7cd8-1195-2825-5655fd33eabd', 'Not Started', 0, '2015-10-14 11:30:00', 0, '2015-10-14 10:45:00', NULL, '', '', 'High'),
('3d62fc14-f606-a737-d76c-565ee38e767b', 'GWENT - VR', '2015-12-02 12:28:27', '2017-04-06 12:39:20', '1', 'e07880a3-a57d-a20c-9e25-565eb7af093f', NULL, 1, '36fcf0ba-7cd8-1195-2825-5655fd33eabd', 'Not Started', 0, '2015-10-23 11:30:00', 0, '2015-10-23 10:45:00', NULL, '', '', 'High'),
('4dd39006-f652-3ae1-d6a6-56718c46617e', 'maghull test 2', '2015-12-16 16:09:01', '2017-04-06 12:37:27', '1', '1', NULL, 1, '1', 'Not Started', 0, '2015-12-12 11:00:00', 0, '2015-12-12 10:00:00', NULL, '', '', 'High'),
('595a2e58-76bc-c134-3cef-58e64b59e8d5', 'c1lesson_last_completed', '2017-04-06 14:08:03', '2017-03-16 14:09:28', '1', '1', NULL, 0, '1', 'Completed', 0, '2015-12-16 11:00:00', 0, '2015-12-16 10:00:00', NULL, '', '', 'High'),
('5ba36af1-8f2b-075b-926f-58cfd87a83e7', 'c1lesson_notyetcompleted', '2017-03-20 13:26:40', '2017-04-06 12:27:12', '1', '1', NULL, 0, 'a691ed76-ef37-ad18-4450-561397563eee', 'Not Started', 1, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, '', '', 'High'),
('6693cd37-0b74-1d97-c395-5672a343260d', 'nocourse_lesson1', '2015-12-17 11:59:11', '2017-04-06 12:39:59', '1', '1', NULL, 0, '1', 'Completed', 0, '2015-12-18 15:00:00', 0, '2015-12-18 14:00:00', NULL, '', '', 'High'),
('7488d168-758c-f760-ed28-57738b5565db', 'c1lesson1', '2016-06-29 08:47:35', '2017-04-06 12:15:28', '1', '1', NULL, 0, '1', 'Completed', 0, '2015-04-06 09:45:00', 0, '2015-04-06 09:00:00', NULL, '', '', 'High'),
('760f5ee8-6470-9291-6733-56718c949974', 'c5lesson2', '2015-12-16 16:09:30', '2017-04-06 12:37:50', '1', '1', NULL, 0, '1', 'Not Started', 0, '2015-12-14 11:00:00', 0, '2015-12-14 10:00:00', NULL, '', '', 'High'),
('80859612-d91f-bd91-8198-577b81c9dd09', 'c3lesson2', '2016-07-05 09:44:33', '2017-04-06 12:24:08', '1', '1', NULL, 0, '1', 'Completed', 1, NULL, 0, '2016-07-05 09:00:00', NULL, '', '', 'High'),
('8a635f3b-9e0f-16aa-5532-58e631257729', 'c1lesson_first_completed', '2017-04-06 12:16:49', '2017-04-06 12:27:36', '1', '1', NULL, 0, '1', 'Completed', 0, '2015-04-06 09:45:00', 0, '2015-04-06 09:00:00', NULL, '', '', 'High'),
('8c8404b6-4e53-5f2b-fcce-577b84f9dceb', 'c3lesson_last_completed', '2016-07-05 09:58:43', '2017-04-06 12:31:22', '1', '1', NULL, 0, '1', 'Completed', 1, NULL, 0, '2016-07-06 09:00:00', NULL, '', '', 'High'),
('92a4c747-b1b7-2949-bcf6-56616ee3b065', 'c4lesson2', '2015-12-04 10:43:35', '2017-04-06 12:33:52', '1', 'c0aa6b17-16d0-baea-c4ae-566162ba3706', NULL, 0, 'a691ed76-ef37-ad18-4450-561397563eee', 'Completed', 0, '2015-10-04 09:30:00', 0, '2015-10-04 08:45:00', NULL, '', '', 'High'),
('9ecdc18e-9187-da7e-54d9-58e635cddf77', 'c4lesson2', '2017-04-06 12:34:10', '2017-04-06 12:34:10', '1', '1', '', 0, 'a691ed76-ef37-ad18-4450-561397563eee', 'Not Started', 0, '2015-10-04 09:30:00', 0, '2015-10-04 08:45:00', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'High'),
('a2058842-e181-b794-6343-56616ef2e0b2', 'c4lesson4_last_completed', '2015-12-04 10:43:35', '2017-04-06 12:35:49', '1', 'c0aa6b17-16d0-baea-c4ae-566162ba3706', NULL, 0, 'a691ed76-ef37-ad18-4450-561397563eee', 'Not Started', 0, '2015-10-19 09:30:00', 0, '2015-10-19 08:45:00', NULL, '', '', 'High'),
('a6c97a12-c6b4-f178-acc1-567673523d06', 'c4lesson_first_completed', '2015-12-20 09:25:15', '2017-04-06 12:33:24', '1', '1', NULL, 0, '1', 'Completed', 0, '2015-07-02 09:00:00', 0, '2015-07-02 09:00:00', NULL, '', '', 'High'),
('b15c0722-19da-79bf-51b2-566aabefc417', 'c2lesson_last_completed', '2015-12-11 10:56:48', '2017-04-06 12:29:58', '1', '1', NULL, 0, '1', 'Completed', 0, '2015-12-16 11:00:00', 0, '2015-12-16 10:00:00', NULL, '', '', 'High'),
('d9fed2e5-a303-e3d6-0c0c-577b814f9e4c', 'c3lesson_first_completed', '2016-07-05 09:44:04', '2017-04-06 12:30:54', '1', '1', NULL, 0, '1', 'Completed', 1, NULL, 0, '2016-07-01 09:00:00', NULL, '', '', 'High'),
('fb94089f-57e9-0918-c98f-56756fa424d4', 'c1lesson2', '2015-12-19 14:55:56', '2017-04-06 12:17:29', '1', '1', NULL, 0, '1', 'Completed', 0, '2015-10-06 09:00:00', 0, '2015-10-06 09:00:00', NULL, '', '', 'High');

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

With the following query, I’m able to get the list of all the ‘completed’ lessons, but I’m in trouble to get just the most recent one per each course… In practice I need the first row, for each course:

I’m not an SQL expert and I really appreciate any help. Thank you.
Piergiorgio

```html
SELECT pj001_courses.name AS Corso,
       pj001_courses.id AS id_corso,
       tasks.id AS idlez,
       tasks.name AS Lezione,
       tasks.date_modified AS date_modified,
       max_dates.max_date_start AS date_start
FROM pj001_courses
JOIN pj001_courses_tasks_c ON pj001_courses.id = pj001_courses_tasks_c.pj001_courses_taskspj001_courses_ida
JOIN tasks ON pj001_courses_tasks_c.pj001_courses_taskstasks_idb = tasks.id
JOIN ( SELECT pj001_courses_tasks_c.pj001_courses_taskspj001_courses_ida AS id_corso,
              MAX( tasks.date_start ) AS max_date_start
       FROM pj001_courses_tasks_c
       JOIN tasks ON pj001_courses_tasks_c.pj001_courses_taskstasks_idb = tasks.id
       WHERE pj001_courses_tasks_c.deleted = 0
         AND tasks.deleted = 0
         AND tasks.status = 'completed'
       GROUP BY id_corso ) max_dates ON max_dates.id_corso = pj001_courses.id
                                    AND max_dates.max_date_start = tasks.date_start
WHERE pj001_courses.deleted = 0
ORDER BY Corso,
         id_corso,
         tasks.date_start DESC,
         tasks.date_modified desc;
```

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are involved?

Comment: Do you require `status` to be part of the output?

Comment: Can two Courses have the same Name?  Can two Tasks have the same ID or Name?

Comment: Id `date_modified` a date or a datetime data type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try...

```
SELECT pj001_courses.name AS Corso,
       pj001_courses.id AS id_corso,
       tasks.id AS idlez,
       tasks.name AS Lezione,
       tasks.date_modified AS date_modified,
       tasks.date_start AS date_start
FROM pj001_courses
JOIN pj001_courses_tasks_c ON pj001_courses.id = pj001_courses_tasks_c.pj001_courses_taskspj001_courses_ida
JOIN tasks ON pj001_courses_tasks_c.pj001_courses_taskstasks_idb = tasks.id
JOIN
(
    SELECT pj001_courses_tasks_c.pj001_courses_taskspj001_courses_ida AS id_corso,
           tasks.date_start AS max_date_start,
           MAX( tasks.date_modified ) AS max_date_modified
    FROM pj001_courses_tasks_c
    JOIN tasks ON pj001_courses_tasks_c.pj001_courses_taskstasks_idb = tasks.id
    WHERE ( pj001_courses_tasks_c.pj001_courses_taskspj001_courses_ida,
            tasks.date_start ) IN ( SELECT pj001_courses_tasks_c.pj001_courses_taskspj001_courses_ida AS id_corso,
                                           MAX( tasks.date_start ) AS max_date_start
                                    FROM pj001_courses_tasks_c
                                    JOIN tasks ON pj001_courses_tasks_c.pj001_courses_taskstasks_idb = tasks.id
                                    WHERE pj001_courses_tasks_c.deleted = 0
                                      AND tasks.deleted = 0
                                      AND tasks.status = 'completed'
                                    GROUP BY id_corso
                                  )
    GROUP BY id_corso
) max_dates_finder ON pj001_courses.id = max_dates_finder.id_corso
                  AND tasks.date_start = max_dates_finder.max_date_start
                  AND tasks.date_modified = max_dates_finder.max_date_modified
WHERE pj001_courses.deleted = 0
ORDER BY Corso,
         id_corso;
```

The following segment produces a list of units assigned to each course where that unit has been completed and has not been deleted from the course or in general.  It then outputs each course's `id` and the most recent value of `date_start` for each course.

```
SELECT pj001_courses_tasks_c.pj001_courses_taskspj001_courses_ida AS id_corso,
       MAX( tasks.date_start ) AS max_date_start
FROM pj001_courses_tasks_c
JOIN tasks ON pj001_courses_tasks_c.pj001_courses_taskstasks_idb = tasks.id
WHERE pj001_courses_tasks_c.deleted = 0
  AND tasks.deleted = 0
  AND tasks.status = 'completed'
GROUP BY id_corso
```

The following segment produces a list of Courses and those units assigned to each course where each entry's course `id` and `date_start` appear in the list generated by the previous segment.  This new list is then refined to just the Course `id`, most recent value of `date_start` for that course and the most recent value of `date_modified` corresponding to that value of `date_start`.

```
SELECT pj001_courses_tasks_c.pj001_courses_taskspj001_courses_ida AS id_corso,
       tasks.date_start AS max_date_start,
       MAX( tasks.date_modified ) AS max_date_modified
FROM pj001_courses_tasks_c
JOIN tasks ON pj001_courses_tasks_c.pj001_courses_taskstasks_idb = tasks.id
WHERE ( pj001_courses_tasks_c.pj001_courses_taskspj001_courses_ida,
        tasks.date_start ) IN ( SELECT pj001_courses_tasks_c.pj001_courses_taskspj001_courses_ida AS id_corso,
                                       MAX( tasks.date_start ) AS max_date_start
                                FROM pj001_courses_tasks_c
                                JOIN tasks ON pj001_courses_tasks_c.pj001_courses_taskstasks_idb = tasks.id
                                WHERE pj001_courses_tasks_c.deleted = 0
                                  AND tasks.deleted = 0
                                  AND tasks.status = 'completed'
                                GROUP BY id_corso
                              )
GROUP BY id_corso
```

This code is then `JOIN`ed with the other tables and refined to only those courses that have not been deleted to produce the code from the beginning of my Answer.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: Pressing Enter finishes the Comment rather than the line.

Comment: Hi toonice and thank you for your answer. Regarding your questions: 1) Status is not necessary in the output. Sorry for that. 2) Courses can have the same name but not the same id, 3) Tasks can have the same name but not the same id. 3) Both tasks.date_start and date_modified are datetime data type. I included 'date_modified' because looking at the data into the db, I realized that there are some duplicated Tasks in terms of name and date_start, so I assume that the last modified is the good one.

Comment: I tried your query, but my msqlfront is giving "error sql #1052. Column 'date_modified' in where clause is ambiguous."

Comment: I have updated my answer to (hopefully) eliminate that error by specifying which table `date_modified` comes from.  I have also refined the `ORDER BY` clause so that a list of `Corso`'s with the same name will be subsorted on `id_corso`.  I shall now check to see if the rest of my answer is compliant with your second most recent Comment.

Comment: the query is now working and is providing the last completed task / last modified task, but is giving just 1 row... so for the first course. I need the same result for each course. Ps. there is a missing ',' on the second line of the query.

Comment: I'll patch it up... hopefully before I go to bed.  And thank you for pointing out the typo.

Comment: I have updated my answer.  I shall edit the explanation in the morning.  Good night.

Comment: Hi @toonice, I posted an answer instead of a comment. I don't know if you had a chance to see it.

Comment: Sorry, but things have gotten a bit crazy here with family medical matters as well as the usual collection of people asking follow-up questions.  Are you still pursuing thsi problem, and if sot, then where do we stand?

Comment: No problem @toonice. There are priorities in life and wish you all the best for your family. Yes, my question is still open. I modified my question to include a test database creation script and my modified query script to be considered as starting point to get the disired result.

Comment: I have corrected the errors in my statement and updated it in my Answer. 
 This has become V1.  I have also added a second statement (V2) that also excludes from the results any `Task` that has been deleted from the `Course` even when that `Task` remains undeleted in `Tasks` and that `Course` remains undeleted in `pj001_courses`, i.e. I have excluded all records from `pj001_courses_tasks_c` where `pj001_courses_tasks_c.deleted = 1`.  This produces a slightly different result set.  Is that the one that you are after?  If not, then how is it different from what you want?

Comment: I tried both V1 and V2, but mysql query reply is:    #1055 - Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'speak_italy_stov.tasks.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: We would appear to be using different SQL modes.  I shall investigate this further.  It might help to know what you get if you try entering `SELECT @@sql_mode;`.  For further reading try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591231/how-can-i-see-the-specific-value-of-the-sql-mode or https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html.

Comment: I tried to load my test db in 2 server and run your queries. In server 1 (5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), (where i get the error message), when I run SELECT @@sql_mode I have this: ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION    . in server 2 (5.5.54-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) I simply get @@sql_mode as reply.

Comment: Anyway @toonice when I run your query in server 2, where it works, the results are not coherent. If you want to check what the result should be, please run my query (In my question) and consider just the first row per each course. The 'Lesson name' will be self explicative.

Comment: Th error message that you received has been addressed in my now much revamped answer.  The code in my answer has been tested against your sample data.  I have examined the sample data and believe that the output specified by your question has been obtained.  If neither piece of code from my Answer works, then please get back to me with a description of how it is not coherent.  You may wish to modify your question to include the output that you desire.  I look forward to hearing from you.

Comment: Almost there @toonice! with the 2nd version of your query. The only non coherent result regards the Course1... the disired record output should be: 'Lesson id' = 2f19dd24-1c2f-a245-1856-566b214d7abd, 'Lesson name' = c1lesson_last_completed .  I noticed that the one coming from your query, re. course1 is the most recently modified...

Comment: After very carefully examining the data I have spotted the problem.  Apparently my knowledge of `GROUP BY` operating in conjunction with aggregate functions is deficient in this situation.  I somehow missed that it was grabbing the first row in our selected list rather than (as expected) grabbing the row with the aggregate function's result).  The first statement  is incorrect.  The second is correct.  My apologies for the confusion.

Comment: we are not yet there... what I need is the most recent completed lesson per each course in terms of DATE_START. The date_modified field filter is necessary only in case there are 2 or more records with the same 'task.name', 'task.date_start' and 'task.status' (basically duplicated records). In this case I assume the 'good one' is the most recent modified. I changed a bit your last working query (see it in my question), but for the first course I get 2 records (because of duplication) instead of just one . Can you give a look?

Comment: Answer revised... again.  This latest version tests as okay.  I am updating the explanation in my Answer now.

Comment: It's working @toonice. Thank you very much! Anyway I have an issue when I run the query with production Database. It take ages to get the result... actually I had to abort the query because after 1/2 hour it was still running. The production db is about 1gb. What could be the problem in your opinion? Just to point me in the right direction...

Comment: There are a number of potential reasons.  The first thing that springs to mind is using long strings as primary keys is very inefficient.  It takes longer for the computer to compare two strings (or join on them, etc.) than to compare two numbers.  Longer strings take longer than short ones.  The effect of this upon your total running time is multiplied by however many records you have - large datasets can lead to a large slowdown.  I recommend that you add an autoincrement field to each table and use that as your primary key.  You can apply the `UNIQUE` constraint to the existing `id` fields.

Comment: Using indexes on commonly searched fields can also lead to a further improvement, but the topic of indexes is *way* too broad to explain here.  You should do some more research into those.  Also, it is often possible to write several different SQL statements to achieve the same result.  If I find a more efficient way than in my Answer, I will contact you.  There are other possible causes, but again that is too broad a topic for me to address here so you will have to research those also.

Comment: Thank you @toonice for your very clear explication. Unfortunately It's not a viable solution to change the primary key of my database. The 3 tables used as test db are just a small portion of the production db of a CRM platform. As per your advice I'll check if the use of indexes can help to mitigate the problem. In the meantime if you find a way to optimize the query using different sql statement, that would be great. Thank you again for all the support.

Answer (score 0):

@toonice some fields name in your last query were not correct. I fixed them, but anyway the results looks not consistent re. date_start and date_modified.I'm new here in Stack Overflow and not sure if I can attach a test database with just 30 / 40 records for query testing purpouse

```html
SELECT pj001_courses.name AS Corso,
       pj001_courses.id AS id_corso,
       tasks.id AS idlez,
       tasks.name AS Lezione,
       tasks.date_start AS date_start,
       MAX( tasks.date_modified ) AS date_modified
FROM pj001_courses
JOIN pj001_courses_tasks_c ON pj001_courses.id = pj001_courses_tasks_c.pj001_courses_taskspj001_courses_ida
JOIN tasks ON pj001_courses_tasks_c.pj001_courses_taskstasks_idb = tasks.id
WHERE tasks.deleted = 0
  AND tasks.status = 'completed'
  AND pj001_courses.deleted = 0
GROUP BY id_corso
ORDER BY Corso,
         id_corso,
         tasks.date_start DESC,
         tasks.id;
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could modify your Question to include a script for creating the tables and populating them with sample data.  Can you create such a script?

Comment: @toonice, I modified my question to include a db creation script and the query script I created as starting point to get the disired result. Let me know if all is ok to recreate my testing environment.

Comment: I've begun testing with your sample data.  After reviewing `tasks` I've noticed that the `date_start` value associated with `id = 5ba36af1-8f2b-075b-926f-58cfd87a83e7` is `NULL`.  Is this supposed to be the case?  Also, in columns like `description`, `parent_id` and `contact_id` you soemtimes use `NULL` and sometimes use `''`.  As a matter of good practice I recommend you standardise to just `NULL`.

Comment: @toonice, re. null date_start,  it's possible that users set a task to be held in the future, but not already planned in terms of fixed date. Re. the others fields I'll check the default value. Thanks for your advice.