# MySQL CHAR variable type in routine not recognizing SPACE character

Tags: mysql

Can someone please tell me why MySQL does not recognize SPACE character when assigned to a CHAR variable?

The sample code below simply echoes back the input char by char into a variable just to demonstrate.

When called using my_test('1    2'), which is 6 chars total input, containing 4 spaces, the result is only '12' two chars returned.

If I change the definition of ch to CHAR(2), CHAR(4), CHAR(10) ...same result.

If I change the definition of ch to VARCHAR(1) it works as I would expect, returning all 6 original chars.

To me, this seems like a bug with CHAR handling on MySQL. The same code using CHAR(1), with minor syntax changes, works fine on Oracle and SQL Server.

Using MySQL 5.7.21

```
/*
    select my_test('1    2'); -- Total len = 6 (contains 4 spaces)
*/

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS my_test;
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION my_test( original VARCHAR(100) )
RETURNS VARCHAR(100) 
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE ch CHAR(1); -- Will only recognize SPACE if changed to VARCHAR!
    DECLARE idx INT DEFAULT 1;    
    DECLARE len INT;
    DECLARE result VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT ''; 

    SET len = CHAR_LENGTH(original);
    WHILE idx <= len DO
        SET ch = SUBSTR(original, idx, 1);
        SET result = CONCAT(result, ch);
        SET idx = idx + 1;
    END WHILE;

RETURN result;

END;
```

Comment: This is a pretty good question and test case. This is not a bug in MySQL. It is a behavior one has to be careful of when using CHAR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are seeing can be resolved by ensuring that the function was created with sql_mode set to `pad_char_to_full_length`.

**Solution**

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS my_test;

SET sql_mode = 'PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH';
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION my_test( original VARCHAR(100) )
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE ch CHAR(1);
    DECLARE idx INT DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE len INT;
    DECLARE result VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '';

    SET len = CHAR_LENGTH(original);
    WHILE idx <= len DO
        SET ch = SUBSTR(original, idx, 1);
        SET result = CONCAT(result, ch);
        SET idx = idx + 1;
    END WHILE;

RETURN result;

END//

delimiter ;
SET sql_mode = '';
```

**Result**

```
select my_test('1  2');
+-----------------+
| my_test('1  2') |
+-----------------+
| 1  2            |
+-----------------+
```

**Explanation**

If you have `CHAR(5)` and you stored `A` in it, MySQL will internally store it as `A`. However, when you select from that `CHAR(5)`, right-padded spaces aren't retrieved UNLESS `pad_char_to_full_length` sql_mode is set. By default, your sql_mode is likely to not have `pad_char_to_full_length`.

According to [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html):

> The length of a CHAR column is fixed to the length that you declare
>   when you create the table. The length can be any value from 0 to 255.
>   When CHAR values are stored, they are right-padded with spaces to the
>   specified length. When CHAR values are retrieved, trailing spaces are
>   removed unless the PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH SQL mode is enabled.

So, `SET ch = SUBSTR(original, idx, 1);` stores empty space in `ch`. However, when extracting information from `ch` MySQL will truncate spaces from the end resulting in empty string.

**sql_mode**
You can see your current sql_mode by typing `select @@sql_mode`. Also see [How can I see the specific value of the sql_mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591231/how-can-i-see-the-specific-value-of-the-sql-mode).

You can review documentation of sql_mode in [MySQL's doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_pad_char_to_full_length).

**Solution without using sql_mode of `pad_char_to_full_length`**

Instead of doing this:

```
SET ch = SUBSTR(original, idx, 1);
SET result = CONCAT(result, ch);
```

Do this instead:

```
SET result = CONCAT(result, SUBSTR(original, idx, 1));
```

This single line assignment will avoid the `CHAR` trickery and give you intended results even with sql_mode does not have `pad_char_to_full_length`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear & detailed explanation.